# Acessing type as object or Array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript.

I have a class Like this

```
class Document {
  constructor (data, id) {
    this.data = data
    this.id = id
  }
}
```

Here I know that Id is going to be `String` but data is going to be either `object` or `array`.

Can someone help me in figuring out what is going to be the interface for it.

[Update:] What have I tried?

I created an interface like this

```
interface Documents {
  data: Array | Object,
  id: Number
}
```

but this gives following error (red underline below array)

> Generic type 'Array' requires 1 type argument(s).

If it makes any difference, I expect my array to be either `empty` or contain list of `objects`

Comment: Have you tried doing it like this: `constructor (data: object | Array<any>, id: string)`?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Updated the question. Can we use interface and if yes then how?

Comment: notation like `number[]`, `string[]` looks more easy for me. Also, when you read them they can be read as "number array" or "string array"

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the underlying type of array, as Array is a type constructor. I would err towards primitive types where possible. Also, if your data is either an object, an empty array, or a list of objects, I would keep simple and just define it as a (possibly empty) list of objects. So you might end up with something like this:

```js
type DocData = [object]
interface DocumentInterface {
  data: DocData
  id: number
}

class Doc implements DocumentInterface {
    data: DocData
    id: number

    constructor (data: DocData, id: number) {
        this.data = data
        this.id = id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Documents` become a generic interface, your `data` need to be an array or a object, what is type of data you store in the array?, or what is type of the object? The type can be something, like `User`, `Store`...

Example:

```
interface Documents<T extends object> {
  data: Array<T> | T;
  id: number; // best practice: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html 
}
```

And you have another type like:

```
interface IUser {
  name: string,
  email: string,
}
```

Now you need to create a document with `data` is a `IUser`:

```
const doc: Documents<IUser> = {
  id: 1,
  data: {
    name: 'Tom',
    email: 'example@mail.com'
  }
}
```

or `data` will store many `IUser`:

```
const docs: Documents<IUser> = {
  id: 1,
  data: [{
    name: 'Tom',
    email: 'example@mail.com'
  }]
}
```

Comment: the `type` of the data in the array isn't consistent

Comment: @anny123 How about `Documents<any>`, you can store anything to the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Document {
    private data: [] | object;
    private id: string;
  constructor (data: [] | object, id:string) {
    this.data = data
    this.id = id
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `Document` is reserved keyword, you might need to lookup

Comment: Updated the question. Can we use interface and if yes then how?